# Using the panel regression on Hedonic data using plm package in R

Tags: r, regression, plm

I am trying to run the panel regression for unbalanced panel in R using the plm package. I am using the 'Hedonic' data to run the same.

I was trying to replicate something similar that is done in the following paper: http://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/math/statlib/R/CRAN/doc/vignettes/plm/plmEN.pdf (page 14, 3.2.5 Unbalanced Panel).

My code looks something like this:

```
form = mv ~ crim + zn + indus + chas + nox + rm + age + dis + rad + tax + ptratio + blacks + lstat
ba = plm(form, data = Hedonic)
```

However, I am getting the following error on execution:

```
Error in names(y) <- namesy : 
  'names' attribute [506] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

traceback() yields the following result:

```
4: pmodel.response.pFormula(formula, data, model = model, effect = effect, 
       theta = theta)
3: pmodel.response(formula, data, model = model, effect = effect, 
       theta = theta)
2: plm.fit(formula, data, model, effect, random.method, random.dfcor, 
       inst.method)
1: plm(form, data = Hedonic)
```

I am new to panel regression and would be really grateful if someone can help me with this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That paper is ten years old, and I'm not sure `plm` works like that. The latest docs are here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf

Your problem arises because, in the docs:

> the current version of plm is capable of working with a regular
>   data.frame without any further transformation, provided that the
>   individual and time indexes are in the first two columns,

The `Hedonic` data set does not have individual and time indexes in the first two columns. I'm not sure where the individual and time indexes are in the data, but if I specify `townid` for the index I at least get something that runs:

```
> p <- plm(mv~crim,data=Hedonic)
Error in names(y) <- namesy : 
  'names' attribute [506] must be the same length as the vector [0]

> p <- plm(mv~crim,data=Hedonic, index="townid")
> p

Model Formula: mv ~ crim

Coefficients:
      crim 
-0.0097455
```

because when you don't specify id and time indexes it is going to try using the first two columns, and in Hedonic that is giving unique numbers for the id, so the whole model falls apart.

If you look at the examples in `help(plm)` you might notice that the first two columns in all the data sets define the id and the time.

Comment: Yes, `townid` is the indentifiyer of the observational units. There is no time index in the data but it is given implicitly by the data order. The current version of the vignette has exactly this example.